# C# NMODBUS Addressing

Tags: c#, modbus

I'm building a project that will be using a PC as a modbus master and a Click plc as a slave device. The communication method is Serial RTU. I'm having a bit of trouble with the addressing system to read and write to the registers in the plc. I've built some test code using the guide here: [C# NModbus DLL with Wago Remote IO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rP8BUNTQ0HQ)

However, I can't get my head around the address system... I want to turn on output Y1 on my PLC, which has a modbus address of: 8193, but the modbus.dll doesn't seem to like it as iv the address is too high or incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

try adding leading zeroes to the address.  8193 should be 008193.